# How to find hexadecimal array for a font to draw it on bitmap

Tags: android, fonts, bitmap, rgba

I have a bitmap surface with `RGBA8888` format that I can draw image on. Now, I would like to add some letters to the image. I figure, I need a `font` which is stored in `RGBA8888` bitmap format. I then need to load the `font` into memory and choose the letter to display from the font and then write it to `bitmap`. But How can I find or extract `RGBA8888 arrays` for a font from `TrueType` font or any other format?

Comment: Several conversion tools linked here on [gamedev.se](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2717/tool-to-create-a-bitmap-font-from-a-true-type-font). For loading it, you can google up some bitmap font tutorials.

Comment: Have you tried [fontforge](http://fontforge.org/)?

Comment: Just tried. It saved a tty file into a bitmap file with bdf extension. How can I open bdf file and read the hexadecimal values out of it for a given character?